# How do I add margin instead of padding in bootstrap columns?

Tags: user-interface, bootstrap-4

when I tried using col-4 for three divs, I had padding in those divs and all were connected together as shown in the images.

```
code https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MDiI.jpg
gutters https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcgOg.jpg
no-gutters https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP844.jpg
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't post images of code

Answer (score 0):

I would go along with your question which isn't asked properly.

Add `p-0` class to all your `col-*` `div`s which will basically reset the padding in between columns, and afterwards you can add `m-*` ; *where * = 1,2,3,4,5* (*i.e. `m-3`*) which will add margin specified in `rem` measurement in between the columns.